# Cannot update .geojson file for app submission on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, geojson, appstore-approval, mac-app-store

My GeoJSON file is supposed to cover the entire world. Here is the GeoJSON file:

```
{ "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
                    [[[-169.4,58.8], [-168.0,83.4], [188.4,83.3], [194.0,-72.8], [-166.6,-73.6], [-169.4,58.8]]]
                    ]
}
```

The name of the file is *example.GeoJSON*.

I keep getting the following error when uploading the file:

> Your routing app coverage file is invalid. For more information see the Developer Guide.

What is wrong with the above file?

My app has a mapkit that shows the annotation of a particular place depending on the place that is chosen. When tapping the map in the app, Apple Maps opens up and shows the directions to that place from the current position. Do I also actually need to upload the .GeoJSON file?

Comment: I believe latitude must be between -180 and 180. You do not need a geojson file to achieve what you describe though. To my knowledge it is used to make the Apple Maps --> Your app link (Apple Maps will propose your app for journey search results)

Comment: Any example that works?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the following:

1) The Latitude goes from -90 into +90 (i.e. this is where you stand on the middle of the globe going either up or down) (AKA vertically).

2) The Longitude goes from 0 to 360 (i.e. standing where you are, and going around the globe in a circle horizontally.

3) The Polygon usually has 4 points, however, in this case it would be 5 whereas the first and last points are the same to denote a closed-polygon.

4) Adding the apple requirements of ( "type": "MultiPolygon" ) plus coordinates,

5) You would end up with the following contents of a file:

```
{ "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
                    [[
                       [-360.0000,-90.0000]
                      ,[-360.0000, 90.0000]
                      ,[-000.0000, 90.0000]
                      ,[-000.0000,-90.0000]
                      ,[-360.0000,-90.0000]
                    ]]
                    ]
}
```

Therefore, start your text editor, and then copy and paste the above, save the file into World.geojson and then upload.

Mine worked fine.

Enjoy!
Heider

Comment: One condition for the multipolygon to be accepted on the AppStore is that it only contains closed polygons (in the form [[ [ , ], ...., [ , ] ]]), and no open lines ( [ [ , ], ... , [ , ] ]. See https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON